# Laravel's Storage::makeDirectory returns mkdir: invalid argument

Tags: php, laravel, directory, mkdir

So I'm trying to create a new directory in `C:/..../public/videos` folder when somebody uploads a video, using the following code:

```
if ($request->hasFile('video')) {
    $newDir = public_path('videos\\' . $story->story_id);
    Storage::makeDirectory( $newDir, 0755, true);
    $request->file('video')->move($newDir);
 }
```

But I get this error:

> ErrorException in Local.php line 350: mkdir(): Invalid argument in
>   Local.php line 350 at HandleExceptions->handleError('2', 'mkdir():
>   Invalid argument',
>   'C:\xampp\htdocs\qanda2\vendor\league\flysystem\src\Adapter\Local.php',
>   '350', array('dirname' => 'C:\xampp\htdocs\qanda2\public\videos\31',
>   'config' => object(Config), 'location' =>
>   'C:\xampp\htdocs\qanda2\storage\app\C:\xampp\htdocs\qanda2\public\videos\31',
>   'umask' => '0', 'visibility' => 'public')) at
>   mkdir('C:\xampp\htdocs\qanda2\storage\app\C:\xampp\htdocs\qanda2\public\videos\31',
>   '493', true) in Local.php line 350 at
>   Local->createDir('C:\xampp\htdocs\qanda2\public\videos\31',
>   object(Config)) in Filesystem.php line 259 at
>   Filesystem->createDir('C:\xampp\htdocs\qanda2\public\videos\31') in
>   FilesystemAdapter.php line 276

It seems like makeDirectory automatically adds `C:\xampp\htdocs\qanda2\storage\app\` in front of my path.

Is there any workaround for this? I've been struggling with this for a while now and I can't find anything about this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a directory, you should use `File`, like this:

```
if ($request->hasFile('video')) {
   $newDir = public_path('videos\\' . $story->story_id);
   File::makeDirectory( $newDir, 0755, true);
   $request->file('video')->move($newDir);
}
```

Comment: The File class is this one right?Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File, there is no method named makeDirectory in that class.

Comment: Oh never mind, it's this one:  Illuminate\Support\Facades\File. Thanks alot!

Comment: If this code is working,please make this answer as accepted,will helpful for others